# Namespaces and Class loading in php

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm new to namespaces in PHP and trying to make use of them to load classes.

Whenever I run my code I get `class Cheese cannot be found on line x`

`PHPstorm` recognizes the class via the namespaces and enables its methods.

I have the following files / directory structure.

```
/Project 
  /App
     Mouse.php
  /Test
     MouseTest.php
```

**Mouse.php**

```
namespace App\Mouse;

class Cheese 
{
}
```

**MouseTest.php**

```
namespace Test\MouseTest;

use \App\Mouse\Cheese as Cheese;

class CheeseTest 
{
   function test() {
        $cheese = new Cheese();
        $cheese->eat();
   } 

}
```

Comment: What kind of autoloader are you using?

Answer (score 1):

if you use `composer` or any autoloader that follow [psr-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/), then file name must same with class name, change `Mouse.php` to `Cheese.php`

Comment: I just noticed the Class was a different name than the file.  I missed that, so yes, not quite PSR0 like I had thought.

Answer (score 0):

PHP namespaces don't load classes automatically, you have to include their files.

To make it automatic (like you want) you have to make an **autoloader** which will load the classes depending on the namespaces that you want to **use**.

The best way to make this, is using composer: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/easy-package-management-with-composer--net-25530

but I recommend to search "php auloader" in google

Comment: Seems to have a certificate error on that site.  It might be better for you to include more details yourself, especially if that site doesn't exist in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a similar structure to the PSR0 standard found here: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

This is an example autoloader following that structure:

```
function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require $fileName;
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

The [**spl_autoload_register**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) call registers the autoload function so when a class is instantiated, it will use your autoload function to retrieve the class definition.

Comment: how would i use this. would i have to predict classes to autoload

Comment: @user3708645, you don't have to predict classes.  The autoload function is invoked with the className.  From the class name, the PSR0 function discerns the location of the file to include.  For example:  App\Mouse\Cheese would look in App/Mouse/Cheese.php for the Cheese class.